# Angular common pitfalls leading to perfromance bottleneck

Tags: jquery, angularjs, performance

I have been handed over a pre-built project, It uses full fledged AngularJS. There are lot of problem regarding the performance of the application.

I have gathered out some of the points which might be making the Application very slow.

1. Extensive use of rootscope for storing data and passing data between controller is making rootscope really big over time. 85-90% of controllers uses rootscope.
2. There are lengthy conditions in ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if etc. Which might be making rendering of html slow.
3. Instead of using child controllers, there are lot of controllers which after loading renders the header/siderbar template again and again.
4. After load of each controller, there are common methods being attached to scope for initializing user and other common entity. I am not sure how much this is affecting the performance.
5. Lot of jQuery code for DOM manipulation inside controllers, specially related to datepicker, drag/drop, WYSIWYG editor. Though they uses $timeout.
6. Whenever there is a POST/PUT entity call, it sort of converts UI string date to timestamp and vice-versa after finishing the operation.

What I am not sure is that are these really bottleneck and making application slow or there might be other bad practices which is going below my radar.

What are (other) common pitfalls which new to Angular guys makes due to their lack of knowledge or time constraints. I want to differentiate these pitfalls with 'strict No' and 'should be avoided'.

Thank you!! and have a great day.

Comment: This link listed some more performance bottlenecks with angular. http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/

Comment: Thanks @WildWidow (!!??), Though I agree to all of them but they come to me more as cliche. They are more to 'improve' the performance and comes as 'should be practiced'.

But I acknowledge I didn't know about debounce option. So Thanks Indeed.

Comment: In my experience, 1,4,6 does not make app slowdown much, but other a lot, when they need to run in every $digest cycle, which happens a lot in big application. 3,5 can take considerable amount of time on js execution, and 2 might hit layout recalc, if there is a lot of DOM changes.